# Is my Wordpress site handing out sensitive information/misconfigured?

Tags: rest-api, security

[This HNQ answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/265425) seems to imply that the URL path `/?rest_route=/wp/v2/users/` may be displaying information that is sensitive, and that perhaps there is some misconfiguration that allows WordPress to display details on that page.

Is there anything to those claims?

When I visit that [url on my self-hosted WordPress site](https://www.sqlserverscience.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/users/), I do indeed get a page full of items, but as far as I can tell there is nothing there that cannot be seen other parts of my site, such as the list of authors.

Should I be concerned?  Is there a way to disable the `/?rest_route` functionality?  Should I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/?rest_route` URL is the non-prettified version of `/wp-json`, which is the [URI the WordPress REST API uses.](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/#routes-vs-endpoints)

The [REST API should not be disabled](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#can-i-disable-the-rest-api) since the Admin UI relies upon it.  Having said that, you can [require the REST API only service authenticated users](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#require-authentication-for-all-requests).  To require authentication, add the following rest_authentication_errors filter:

```
add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', function( $result ) {
    // If a previous authentication check was applied,
    // pass that result along without modification.
    if ( true === $result || is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
        return $result;
    }

    // No authentication has been performed yet.
    // Return an error if user is not logged in.
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return new WP_Error(
            'rest_not_logged_in',
            __( 'You are not currently logged in.' ),
            array( 'status' => 401 )
        );
    }

    // Our custom authentication check should have no effect
    // on logged-in requests
    return $result;
});
```

I added it to my `/wp-includes/rest-api.php` file as part of the `rest_api_default_filters()` function definition.  Clearly, this will be overwritten as soon as a new version of WordPress is release, so this is only a temporary measure.  When I visit my site via the REST API url above, without being authenticated, I see the following:

[image]

Comment: Putting the code into a plugin would be the recommended way to survive version updates.