# is exposed wp-admin site a serious security vulnerability

Tags: wp-admin, security

this is a basic question that i was unable to wrap my head around via chat gpt or google, namely is it a serious security vulnerability for a wordpress site to have publicly available wp-admin (login page)?

I do often see serious companies having this, as well as /wp-json/wp/v2/users open which does let me (?) brute force their passwords or reset them ?

Comment: It's common for security plugins to block the user list I think yes.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a credential stuffing attack against the login page in my logs, but I doubt any of the sites I've worked on are serious targets. You can always IP restrict the login page or add 2FA - I guess it's up to you if you think this is a risk or not.

Comment: thanks for the answer Rup - i'm a newbie but what i'm thinking is that if i can reset one's password i can do that and follow up to the genuine reset email sent to the user with a phishing attempt.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/410417/is-my-wordpress-site-handing-out-sensitive-information-misconfigured is related and also worth reading.